# Regular Expression Algorithm

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm, dynamic, expression

I need to write an algorithm that determines if word W is from language L which is described by regular expression.

For example: `L = {a, b, c}*, RegEx = ab+c.a+ (regular expression is given in Reverse Polish notation)`, and the word is `ac`. Here I need to determine if word `ac` satisfies to our regular expression.

Currenty I can solve this problem only when there's no `*`.

Here's my code:

```
void Recognize(string RegEx, string word) {
    string op1;
    bool iop1;
    string op2;
    bool iop2;
    stack <pair<string, bool>> st;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < regEx.size(); ++i) {
        string c = "";
        c.assign(1, regEx[i]);
        if (c == "." || c == "+" || c == "*") {
            if (c == ".") {
                op1 = st.top().first;
                iop1 = st.top().second;
                st.pop();
                op2 = st.top().first;
                iop2 = st.top().second;
                st.pop();
                if (iop1 == true && iop2 == true) {
                    st.push(make_pair(op1 + op2, true));
                }
                else {
                    st.push(make_pair(op1 + op2 + ".", false));
                }
            }
            if (c == "+") {
                op1 = st.top().first;
                iop1 = st.top().second;
                st.pop();
                op2 = st.top().first;
                iop2 = st.top().second;
                st.pop();
                if ((iop1 == true && iop2 == false) || (iop1 == false && iop2 == true)) {
                    st.push(make_pair(op1 + op2 + "+", true));
                }
                else {
                    st.push(make_pair(op1 + op2, false));
                }
            }
            if (c == "*") {
                // I have no idea what to do here.
            }
        }
        else {
            string temp;
            temp.assign(1, word[cnt]);
            if (c == temp) {
                st.push(make_pair(c, true));
                ++cnt;
                if (cnt == word.size()) {
                    cnt = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                st.push(make_pair(c, false));
            }

        }
    }
    if (st.top().second == true) {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have some ideas about using recursion but I'm not sure about that.

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex a.k.a dont reinvent the wheel, mainly this kind of wheel

Comment: @Creris Sorry, but I have to it on my own without additional libraries.

Comment: well then I will not be of help :(

Comment: @Creris It's very serious problem for me. If it's possible, please, share this question with somebody.

Comment: There are 2 approaches: either go the backtracking approach that is used in most engines, or build DFA approach that is described in books.

Comment: It is not clear how your reverse polish notation is built, and why `ab+c.a+` describes `L = {a, b, c}*`.

Comment: @n.m. regex determine the structure of words set. For example: if you have regex `ab+` (which is equivalent to `a + b`) that means that only `a` and `b` satisfies this regex. Language `L = {a,b,c}*` means that we can use `a, b, c` and null to build words.

Comment: @n.m.: The example regex is equi. to `(a|b)c|a` in normal regex.

Comment: You are using non-standard terminology and notation which makes it harder than necessary to help you. `L = {a,b,c}*` seems to mean, in standard terminology, that your alphabet is `{a,b,c}`, not that your language is some specific language over that alphabet. Is that correct? What `+` and `.` mean is still unclear from your problem description. I guess `+` is "either/or" and `.` is "followed by", or is it the other way around?

Comment: Almost each country has its own terminology so for me its difficult to understand you too :) But yes, `{a,b,c}*` equals that we can use a, b and c. `+` means `OR` and `.` means `AND` which means we should use both letters.

Comment: Unrelated. Why on earth do you write `((iop1 == true && iop2 == false) || (iop1 == false && iop2 == true))` instead of `(iop1 || iop2)`? Of course, they don't mean the same thing, but I believe the intendeded meaning of the `+` operator is `(iop1 || iop2)`. Or for that matter `((iop1 == true) && (iop2 == true))` instead of `(iop1 && iop2)`? It's just pointless obfuscation. `iop1` and `iop2` are booleans.

Comment: @rici No, `+` is not really OR. `+` is true when only one of the operands is true but not both.

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: That's a very idiosyncratic definition of `OR`; I've never seen `+` used that way in *any* regular expression language. If it is really what you meant, you need to be extra-clear about that. Also, `.` does not mean `AND` (conjunction). It means concatenation: first `a`, then `b`. Regular expressions are closed over conjunction but it's rarely implemented.

Comment: @rici Ok. Next time I will be more clear.

Comment: @rici: It is widely used in theoretical regular expression, none in regex implementations.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I'm aware of a lot of theoretical literature on regular expressions and I have *never* seen an exclusive-or operator. (Unless you're just referring to the use of the plus sign, in which case you didn't read the comments carefully enough.) If you have a citation, I'd be fascinated to see it.

Comment: @rici: I thought I understood the regex (in some comments in front), so I missed the comment about exclusive or. However, exclusive or doesn't really make sense in a regular expression.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Exactly my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to(or can't) use standard library for working with regular expressions, you can do it this way:

1. Build an epsilon-NFA for this regular expression.
2. Remove epsilon transitions.
3. Convert this NFA to a DFA.
4. Traverse the DFA and see if the final state is terminal or not.

If it is not feasible to build a DFA, there is one more way to do it: running depth first search. The vertices are pairs(string prefix length, state in the NFA). The edges are edges in the NFA. Then you need to check if a pair(entire string length, terminal state) is reachable for at least one terminal state. This approach has polynomial space and time complexity(because the number of states in the NFA is a polynomial of regex lenght).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not very good way to solve the problem. Making DFA takes too much time.

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: Then use the backtracking approach. You will run the backtracking directly on the NFA created from the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh There's no need to make NFA or DFA. This problem gonna be solved with using dynamic programming. Look at my code, I use it there to work with + and .